# parsing nested json array without labels in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a nested json array looking like this:

```
[
    [
        [
            [1234.5 ,9876,5],
            [1234.5 ,9876,5]
        ],
        [
            [1234.5 ,9876,5],
            [1234.5 ,9876,5]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            [1234.5 ,9876,5],
            [1234.5 ,9876,5]
        ],
        [
            [1234.5 ,9876,5],
            [1234.5 ,9876,5]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I already saw many posts with answers if you have named keys in objects. However I just have large, nested array's. How should you make objects which can store this in c#? The length of the array's can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<List<List<List<int>>>>
```

Comment: sorry, didnt notice you had floating numbers there

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the start @user2033402

Using the package "NewtonSoft" i got it working using the following line as an example:

```
var results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<List<double>>>>>(nestedJsonarray);
```